# Roots of characteristic function of "reciprocal gamma measure"

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, fourier-transform

Let us call a measure $\mu$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{B}_{(0,\infty)}$ of subsets of $(0,\infty)$ a *reciprocal gamma measure* if it is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m_L$ on $((0,\infty),\mathfrak{B}_{(0,\infty)})$ with the Radon-Nikodym derivative given by $$\frac{d\mu}{dm_L}(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\quad\text{for } x\in (0,\infty).$$
Let $\varphi$ be the characteristic transformation of the reciprocal gamma measure, that is, the complex valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$\varphi(u)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\!e^{ixu}\, \mu(dx)\quad\text{for } u \in \mathbb{R}.$$

**Question:** Is the collection of all zeros  $\{u\in\mathbb{R}\colon \varphi(u)=0\}$ an empty set?

**Remarks I:** From numerical inspections, I am tempted to believe that the answer is in the affirmative. But I do not think there are any standard methods of deciding whether or not there are any zeros.

If we set $c=\varphi(0)$ then $c^{-1}\frac{d\mu}{dm_L}$ is a density of a probability measure $\lambda$ on $\mathfrak{B}_{(0,\infty)}$ having moments of every order. It is well known that if $\lambda$ is infinitely divisible, then $\varphi(u)$ is non-zero for every real number $u\in\mathbb{R}$. I have not been able to verify this infinite divisibility for $\lambda$. I have scrolled through the pages of Steutel & van Harn's book on infinitely divisible probability distributions, but I have not found anything on a probability distribution where the density is given by the reciprocal gamma function normalized. I therefore do not think it is known whether or not the probability distribution $\lambda$ is infinitely divisible. The density is not likely to belong to the class *Bondesson* so it might be very difficult to determine whether or not it is infinitely divisible.

Now the moments of the probability distribution $\lambda$ satisfy Carleman's condition so that $\lambda$ is "determined", that is, there are no other probability distributions on $((0,\infty),\mathfrak{B}_{(0,\infty)})$ having the same sequence of moments. As far as I can tell, the characteristic transformation can be extended to an entire holomorphic function and this too gives that the distribution is determined.

**Remarks II:** It is immediate, from the continuity of $\varphi$, that the set $\Lambda=\{u\in \mathbb{R}\colon \varphi(u)\neq 0\}$ is an open set in the Euclidean metric topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, since 0 is an element of $\Lambda$, it is a nonempty set. To prove that the collection of zeros of $\varphi$ is an empty set, according to the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$, it suffices to show that $\Lambda$ is also a *closed* subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I have not been able to prove that $\Lambda$ is closed, but perhaps my patience was too short.

Comment: You didn't mention the integral representation $\varphi(u) = e^{{iu}+e^{iu}}+\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}\ dt}{(\ln t-iu)^2+\pi^2}$ (the corresponding formula for the Laplace transform, $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ux}\ dx}{\Gamma(x)}=e^{-u+e^{-u}}+\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}\ dt}{(\ln t+u)^2 + \pi^2}$ is proved in a paper by Fransén & Wrigge, _in_ Math. Computation, 1984).  Observe that a _complex_-valued function of a _real_ variable "generally" has no zeroes, so it would be surprising if $\varphi$ had zeroes. On the other hand, if $dx/\Gamma(x)$ was infinitely divisible it should be well known...

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer. It's just a comment about the above integral representation.

If $H$ is a Hankel contour to the left ( a path that comes from $\infty$ with argument $-\pi$, turns around 0 - always at a distance from 0 bigger than 1) and then comes back to $\infty$ with argument $\pi,$ we have
$${1\over{\Gamma (z)}}={1\over {2\pi i}}\int_H {{ e^t}\over {t^z}}dt, \ \ z\in C,$$
where $t^z$ uses a branch of the logarithm $L,$ with $-\pi <Im L <\pi.$

When we compute now its Fourier transform, we can interchange integrals and write
$$\varphi (u)=\int_0^{\infty} {1\over{\Gamma (z)}}e^{iz u}dz={1\over {2\pi i}}\int_H \int_0^\infty e^te^{izu}e^{-z L t}dzdt={1\over{2\pi i}}\int_H {{ e^t}\over{ Lt-iu} }dt.$$
For $u\in (-\pi,\pi),$ we can deform the path to the negative real line plus a circle surrounding the singularity $e^{iu},$ and so  we get
$$\varphi(u)= e^{iu}e^{e^{iu}}+\int_0^\infty{{e^{-t}}\over{(\log t-iu)^2+\pi^2}}dt, \ \ \ \ u\in (-\pi,\pi).$$
Diferently, for $ u\in R-[-\pi,\pi],$ we write:
$$\varphi(u)= \int_0^\infty{{e^{-t}}\over{(\log t-iu)^2+\pi^2}}dt, \ \ \ \ u\not\in [-\pi,\pi].$$

Comment: That's right, and it leads to a potentially useful alternative expression, $\varphi(u) = \lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\exp(-\lambda e^{i\theta})e^{i\theta}\ d\theta}{\log\lambda+i(\theta-u-\pi)}$ (using a contour integral $\oint_\mathcal{C}\frac{f(s)\ ds}{s-iu-i\pi}$ with $f(s):=\exp(s-e^s)$, $f(s+2\pi i)= f(s)$, and $\mathcal{C}=$ the rectangle $[-\log\lambda,+\log\lambda]$, $[\log\lambda,\log\lambda+2\pi i]$, $[\log\lambda+2\pi i, -\log\lambda+2\pi i]$ and $[-\log\lambda+2\pi i,-\log\lambda]$). Some asyptotic analysis might give something, I guess...

Comment: Sorry for the sign mistake: $\varphi(u)=-\lim$ etc